# How can I get verbs, nouns, adjectives from brown corpus?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, corpus, pos-tagger

I have been trying to get all the nouns, verbs..etc separately from the brown corpus, so I tried to use the code

```
brown.all_synsets('n')
```

but apparently this code works with wordnet only. I am using python 3.4 by the way.

---

## EDITED

@alvas answer worked. But when I used it with random it gets an error. Have a look.

```
nn = {word for word, pos in brown.tagged_words() if pos.startswith('NN')}
print(nn)
```

the output is

```
{'such', 'rather', 'Quite', 'Such', 'quite'}
```

but when I use

```
random.choice(nn)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aziz/Desktop/2222.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(random.choice(NN))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 256, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post an answer to response to other answers, edit your question instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It's how words are tagged in Brown, there's no choice but to accept the tags since they are mostly treated as Gold/Silver standards (i.e. ground truth).

Comment: Are you sure you get 'rather' in your output? I didn't =(

Comment: Yes I just made some alterations.
the actual code was 
{word for word, pos in brown.tagged_words() if pos.startswith('NN')}

but i changed it to 
[word for word, pos in brown.tagged_words() if pos.startswith('NN')]

and it woked with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> {word for word, pos in brown.tagged_words() if pos.startswith('NN')}
```

---

**In Longer**

Iterate through the `.tagged_words()` function and that will return a list of `('word', 'POS')` tuples:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown.tagged_words()
[(u'The', u'AT'), (u'Fulton', u'NP-TL'), ...]
```

Please read this chapter to know how NLTK corpora API works: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html

Then, do a list comprehension over it and save a set (i.e. unique list) of the words that are tagged with the noun tags, e.g. `NN, NNS, NNP, etc.`.

```
>>> {word for word, pos in brown.tagged_words() if pos.startswith('NN')}
```

Note that the output *might not* be what you expect because words that are POS tagged with syntactic and **syntactic noun is not necessary a semantic argument/entity**.

---

Also, I don't think that the words you've extracted are correct. Double checking the list:

```
>>> nouns = {word for word, pos in brown.tagged_words() if pos.startswith('NN')} 
>>> 'rather' in nouns
False
>>> 'such' in nouns
False
>>> 'Quite' in nouns
False
>>> 'quite' in nouns
False
>>> 'Such' in nouns
False
```

The output to the list comprehension: http://pastebin.com/bJaPdpUk

---

**Why `random.choice(nn)` fails when `nn` is a set?**

The input to `random.choice()` is a sequence (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice).

> **random.choice(seq)**
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence
>   seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

And python sequence types in python are

- `str, unicode, list, tuple, bytearray, buffer, xrange` in Python 2.x (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).
- `list, tuple, range` in Python 3.x (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)
- (binary sequence types) `bytes, bytearray, memoryview` in Python 3.x
- (text string sequence) `str` in Python 3.x

Since `set` isn't a sequence, you will get the `IndexError`.

Comment: Please add some supporting text for this code snippet.  Explain why it would solve the OP's problem.  Help others to understand.

Comment: Sure @APC, sorry was prepapring breakfast so did a quick answer.

Comment: Just thought you'd like to know, as this appeared in the Low Quality Post review.  As you're doing breakfast, I like my eggs sunny side up :)

Comment: @alvas, Will the code work if I'm using my own corpus? as I can see in that case there won't be `.tagged_words()` method. Any hint?